# How to install node-opus on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm hosting an app with node.js, but for some reason after running 'npm install node-opus', and then requiring it in the app.js, it says that it can't find node-opus. This leads me to believe that node-opus did not install, so I poked around a bit and I saw that this presumably worked for Linux.

Is there a way I can run it in Windows? Thanks

Comment: Did `npm install node-opus` really work correctly? For me it it ERRs because of missing "PYTHON env variable".

Comment: Yeah a bunch of errors, not really sure what they meant, but I got that for installing other modules and I had no trouble requiring them.